# Hardware Ethernet IP Limitation

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

In Linux Environment

How many number of IP address I can assign to a Hardware ethernet interface ? Is there any limitation ?

what is the maximum no. of virtual ethernet interface I can assign to a hardware ethernet interface ?

Comment: I would imagine that the limit on the number of IPv4 addresses on a single interface is approximately 4.3e9.

Answer (score 2):

As of Linux 2.2, there is no limit to the number of aliases an Ethernet interface can have.